# Returning the Connection from JDBC into a main method of Java?

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to return the type Connection?
And use it as a method passed by reference through out the program?
I find it makes the database interaction a lot easier if it is passed as a method.

```
public static Connection database(String database, String username, String password) {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql:" + database;

        //LOAD DRIVER
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        //CONNECT TO DATABASE
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;            
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    db = database("java_jdbc", "admin", "fake_password_1234");      
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that.

Just remember to invoke `close()` on the connection to release its resources when done.

Comment: Could you please review the code I have posted as it seams that there is no connection datatype? Maybe I should import it?

Comment: @Aaron you're missing `java.sql.Connection db` in your main method

Answer (score 1):

```
package mySystem;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MySqlConnector {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection ConnectDB() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //register jdbc driver
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventory_db", "root", "");
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to db");
            return conn;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```